# Is there any WebRTC library for linux?

Tags: linux, webrtc

Is there a library that can do video streaming with a WebRTC enabled browser from a linux application (not from another browser)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is the [WebRTC Native API](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/). It is written in C++(some C in there as well) and can be compiled on Linux, Windows, and OSX. It also contains sample apps that are written in C++ that work on Linux that are able to make calls with a browser.

Checkout the [getting started guide](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/overview) and try and build some of their example apps that run natively.

Comment: Thanks, so if i compile with this library i should be able to create peer to peer between non browser application and with browser right ?

Comment: Yes, you can. I have done by compiling for Android before. There are also projects that example this for iOS as well. I am sure there are windows and linux examples somewhere too.

Comment: your getting started guide link is not working. Can you update that

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this, its awesome
https://github.com/ging/licode/

Comment: I am bit confused, is it possible to use non browser app too as a one of the peer ?